# symbol not recognized buttonplay

Tags: java, android

I have been trying all day to get this little code to work I got farther because I skipped it but needed to come back to it my buttonPlay is not being recognized and my book is telling me I need to import a directive. How do I this

// this is the entry point to our game

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Here we set our UI layout as the view
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Get a reference to the button in our layout
    final Button buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
    buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you are talking about this line:

```
final Button buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
```

The compiler is complaining about this part: `R.id.buttonPlay`.  It is saying that *that* use of `buttonPlay` is an undefined symbol.

The `R` class is actually automatically generated from the XML file that contains your app's UI design.  It includes names for various elements.  The most likely explanation of the compilation error is that either "buttonPlay" has not been defined in the XML, or you deleted it, or you have not spelled the name the same (including capitalization) in the two places.

Comment: yes this has worked for me thank you for your help sorry for the late reply